How to provide internet access to a Tftpd64 DHCP server on Windows?
On my Windows 10 machine, I have set up a DHCP server using Tftpd64. However with my connection I want to also provide internet to the clients on the server. Are there any specific configurations or tools required to route internet traffic through the local DHCP server in this context? My current settings are in the screenshot below:

My connection that is acting as my DHCP server interface is currently "Ethernet 9" which I have statically assigned to 50.50.4.13 along with the following below:

Currently, I have no trouble pinging the machines, but those machines have problems connecting to 8.8.8.8:


How have you configured this? What is your network config?

@music2myear Good point. I have updated with current configuration.


Are there any specific configurations or tools required to route internet traffic through the local DHCP server in this context?

That's literally the kind of information that a DHCP server is configured to advertise to its clients – the Def. router (opt.3) DHCP lease option in your screenshot.
Don't confuse a DHCP server with a router, however. Most routers have a DHCP server, but merely having a DHCP server doesn't turn the system into a router – DHCP server software does not handle the forwarding of IP traffic, it merely gives out the information.
In other words, just because the devices route their traffic through your server like the lease parameter tells them, doesn't automatically mean that the traffic will be routed from that server anywhere further. (And that's something that a basic "ping" test doesn't let you distinguish – you have to actually look at packet captures to know which step your traffic is stuck on.)
Routing is usually an OS built-in feature, and technically available on Windows where you can enable it using the IPEnableRouter registry key. (Or using Internet Connection Sharing, though that forces the use of its own DHCP server instead.)

https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows

Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
Value: IPEnableRouter
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 1

Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled

Use Wireshark (or MS Network Monitor) to see whether packets arrive at your secondary Ethernet interface, and whether they leave through the primary interface.


Related to that, the rest of your network also needs to know a route back to the 50.50.4.0/24 subnet as well (why are you using a Frontier Communications IP address range for it though?), i.e. you'll need to configure a route in your upstream gateway, or you'll need your "Windows router" to also do NAT (like home gateways do).

A route from your LAN router via the Windows system would look like:
Destination: 50.50.4.0/24
Gateway: your Windows system's LAN IP address
(not the 50.50.4.1 one, but the one already known by your LAN router)


Route configuration is preferable but NAT might be easier (sometimes the only option with locked-down home routers). As far as I know, Windows 10 has at least two NAT engines, the newer one is part of Hyper-V as the New-NetNat PowerShell cmdlet and the other is part of the aforementioned ICS.

Hyper-V NAT network setup guide: (doesn't actually require the use of a VM, it merely needs Hyper-V to be installed)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network


